# Uploading to Vimeo through API with different permission settings for the video

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am uploading the video to Vimeo using the pull method using the following call (taken from https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php#upload-videos-from-a-url):

`$video_response = $lib->request('/me/videos', array('type' => 'pull', 'link' => $url), 'POST');`

Everything works, I was wondering how would I send the extra parameters to set the privacy to hide from listing it on Vimeo? Is it possible or only the option is to set the permission from the video ID returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Vimeo global privacy settings respect all uploaded videos, API included. From their [documentation](https://vimeo.com/help/faq/managing-your-videos/privacy-settings#how-do-i-change-the-privacy-on-all-my-videos-at-once):

> Global Video Settings allow you to apply privacy preferences to all of
>   your existing videos and set preferences for future uploads. Go to
>   your Profile and click Settings. From there, go to the Videos tab and
>   make your choices! Then click Save as default. Check the box next to
>   "Also, apply to existing videos" to do just that.

As an alternative, you can manually change them once they are uploaded. I don't believe there is a way to modify privacy settings on a case-by-case basis for each API upload.

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way by using the privacy.view attribute, and setting it to unlisted in the POST payload to upload the video

```
privacy: {
"view":"unlisted"
}
```

is the object.